# Time Complexity--Algorithm Lists

Tags: python, list, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I need to get the value in which the lists differ, and that their complexity time is less than O(n)
However when using a for loop and the operator the complexity is O (n^2)
Both lists are sorted in ascending order and only differ by one element.

Examples:

```
     A1 = [1, 8, 9, 11, 14, 20, 31]; A2 = [1, 8, 9, 11, 20, 31]
      Output: 4

     A1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 123, 125]; A2= [1, 3, 5, 7, 123]
      Output: 5
```

My solution:

```
 for k in range(len(A1)):
  if A1[k] not in A2:
     print(A1[k])
     break
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: "Write an algorithm that returns the value of the extra element in A1"

Comment: Note that O(n*2) = O(n)

Comment: The algorithm must have a complexity time less than O (n) and my solution has O (n ^2)

Comment: Since the inputs are already sorted, why don't you just compare the lists elementwise from the beginning, and stop when the elements differ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# we take the smallest length if both are of unequal length
sz = len(A1) < len(A2) ? len(A1) : len(A2)

differentIndex = -1
# there is only one different element
for k in range(sz):
  if A1[k] != A2[k]:
     differentIndex  = k
     break


if differentIndex  == -1:
    differentIndex = sz + 1

print differentIndex
```

Comment: Why would you not just use **Python comments**?